# 400 bad request when connecting android to django

Tags: android, django, django-rest-framework, retrofit2, bad-request

I am trying to upload a clicked picture from android to Django API, but I am getting 400 Bad Request when I tried debugging with logging interceptor. I have surfed all the similar posts but none helped.

My Django API works fine when I try uploading an image from local drive, the problem is only when I tried to POST an image from android to backend. It would be very nice if anyone could help me.

This is what my logging interceptor looks like
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoB40.png]

This is what my Django API looks like:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1ueV.png]

Django Views.py

```
from rest_framework.generics import (CreateAPIView)
from image_app.models import MyImage
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import viewsets


class ImageCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = MyImage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = imageSerializer
```

Method in Main Activity

```
        public void uploadPicture(File imageFile, Uri uri ){
        System.out.println("The imagefile is stored in "+imageFile);
        OkHttpClient.Builder clientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        clientBuilder.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);
        /*Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(DjangoApi.DJANGO_SITE)
                .client(clientBuilder.build())

                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
*/
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(DjangoApi.DJANGO_SITE)
                .client(clientBuilder.build())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        Log.d("Django post API", retrofit+"");


        DjangoApi postApi= retrofit.create(DjangoApi.class);


        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), imageFile);
        MultipartBody.Part multiPartBody = MultipartBody.Part
                .createFormData("model_pic", imageFile.getName(), requestBody);



        Call<RequestBody> call = postApi.uploadFile(multiPartBody);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<RequestBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<RequestBody> call, Response<RequestBody> response) {
                Log.d("good", "good");

            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<RequestBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("fail", "fail");
            }
        });


    }
```

Interface of Django API in android end

```
public interface DjangoApi {

    String DJANGO_SITE = "http://192.168.0.102:8000/image/";

    @Multipart
    @POST("upload/")
    Call<RequestBody>  uploadFile(@Part MultipartBody.Part file);

}
```

Comment: share the error which you are getting while calling image API.

Comment: search for how to send a file in request body and use it with a post request 

the log you share have this line with is a validation error form backend as there is no file has been sent or an empty file {"model_pic": ["the submmited file is empty."]}

Comment: @AkashPagar Check the Logging Interceptor

Comment: @MohamedAbdEl-hameed I do understand that an empty file has been sent, but I am not sure what else to change in the code. While surfing, that's the way I have seen tutorials to apply. It's better if you can share the code lines to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Your image file not a file 
1_ check file exists in android storage 
2_check your storage permission in android device 
3_ check place that load image from storage and paste here